# Is a PHP function done every time called?

Tags: php, performance

Is a PHP function done on the server side each time I call it?
I am asking this because I wan't to know if it affects my performance.

Example:

```
<?php
  function really_long_loop() {
    $array = array();
    for ($i=1; $i < 1000; $i++) {
      array_push($array, $i);
    } 
    return $array;
  }


  function FirstFunction() {
    $get_loop = really_long_loop();
  }

  function SecondFunction() {
    $get_loop = really_long_loop();
  }
?>
```

In this example does it do the long loop twice, or just once?

Comment: It never does it since you never execute either function that calls it

Comment: ↑ But, if you called the functions, then yeah it would run the loop twice.

Comment: Why would it not? I mean, if you call it then yes, it's gonna be executed - Something would be broken if you call a function and it doesn't execute.

Comment: thanks, Phiter. That answers my question clearly

Comment: I have no knowledge of how PHP actually works in the server. But yes the functions are ment to be executed. The thing is I have a really long query. But I need to call it in two different functions.

Comment: Sven, in this case you should save the results in a variable, like I said in my answer.

Comment: if is in the same session, try to call it once and store the result if the result is the same (for both functions), if not find a way to make the loop faster.

Comment: There's no automatic caching for function results built-in PHP so yes they will run from  beginning to end each time you call them. If you have a long-running function that will always return the same result for the same input, then you could cache the result via e.g. storing it in a local/global/session/database entry and recover it rather than re-running the function. However many functions may return a different result even with the same input, such as e.g. ones that get additional input from the session, cookies or database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now let's run your functions. In this case, you'll be running the loop twice. That's intended, of course.

```
<?php
 FirstFunction();
 SecondFunction();
?>
```

You could apply your function's return to a variable, then the variable would hold the value, and the loop wouldn't be executed again when you call this variable.

If you'll need the same value from the loop in two places in your page, you could do this:

```
<?php
    $loopResult = really_long_loop();

?>
```

Your `$loopResult` variable will hold the value for the rest of the code execution, except inside functions, where you would need to pass this variable as a parameter.

When you call , for example, `$foo = $loopResult`, the loop function won't run again.

Comment: I accidentaly put the return out of the loop (and I can't edit because of my noob account). But what you mean is that I set a global variable and then hold the return value there?

Comment: Not exactly, I'll write more.